# How to make Global Policy/Middleware/Gate in Laravel for similar requests

Tags: authentication, authorization, laravel-7

I use Laravel 7 and these are my routes:

**api.php**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:api']], function () {
  Route::get('posts/{id}', 'PostController@view');
  Route::delete('posts/{id}', 'PostController@destroy');
  Route::put('posts/{id}', 'PostController@update');
  /**
  *
  * Continues similar CRUD requests ...
  * 
  */
  Route::get('comments/{id}', 'CommentController@view');
  Route::delete('comments/{id}', 'CommentController@destroy');
  Route::put('comments/{id}', 'CommentController@update');
  /**
  *
  * Continues similar CRUD requests ...
  * 
  */
});
```

I want only the owner of id of post/comment/... to be able to make changes on those.

e.g: `$post->user_id === $user->id`

or unless the user is admin (`$user->role == 'admin'`).

It doesn't make sense to create multiple Policies (`PostPolicy`, `CommentPolicy`, `TagPolicy` ...) that they do the same similar thing.

I'm looking for a one global policy/middleware development to authenticate these similar requests.

e.g.: `->middleware('isAdminOrself')`

How can I do that?